# Simplify a Wordpress shortcode (or: "custom shortcode")

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

I use a shortcode to display my images on my Wordpress template.

```
[photo id="13927101803" caption="Some text"] // Flickr
[photo id="mqEqHAC3rK"] // Instagram, no caption
```

Because I write my posts in Markdown, it's kind of boring to write these [attr="ibutes"] when I have 10 photos or more to include.
That's why I'm looking to simplify these photos includes to have something like that :

```
[13927101803 "Caption"] // Flickr
[mqEqHAC3rK] // Instagram

// Causes a conflict with the links in Markdown [this is](http://a-link)… ?
```

When I save a post, it runs a hook which detects the shortcodes, call the Flickr/Instagram API to get the source image url and stock it into the database (with an array of each photo for each post).

Here is my current code to catch the shortcodes: http://pastebin.com/TVEQKudg

Any way to simplify these calls? Or another idea to call it quickly and don't use these long shortcodes?

Comment: Explain in simple words. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Use this ```[13927101803 "Caption"]``` instead of this ```[photo id="13927101803" caption="Some text"]```
:)

Comment: This `13927101803` and this `mqEqHAC3rK` will change later on? Are these ids is for single image>

Comment: Yep it changes for every image, but the ID is always 11 digits for flickr and 10 [a-zA-Z0-9] for Instagram

Comment: No you can't. Wordpress shortcodes must have unique placeholder describing the shortcode like you have **`[photo ...]`**. Thats why you have attributes is for to modify dynamic data `key/value` pairs.

Comment: I know I can't with the `add_shortcode` function, but as I don't really use it as a shortcode, can't I "detect" these "custom" shortcodes in the content and do the process? It's more about a `preg_match_all` regex than a function I think (but I'm really bad at it…).

Comment: Or maybe if it's not a shortcode, maybe another way to declare it, like `§13927101803 "caption"§` or anything else?

Comment: Yes you can do that way.

Comment: I think too! Do you have an example on how to detect it, the id and the caption?

Comment: Try yourself first with your idea. If you can't come back i'll crack it for you.

Comment: Actually I'm really bad… I will take hours to try to do something doesn't working haha

Comment: Is caption is optional to match?

Comment: Yep the caption is optional. Maybe can be matched by > "< just after the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here you go:

```
/\[(\d{11}|\w{10})(?:\s*"([^"]+)")?\]\/
```

Lets say you have this content:

> Simple testing [13927101801 "Caption"] [mqEqHAC3rK "caption"]Simple
>   testing Simple testing Simple testinga Simple testing Simple testinga
>   Simple testing Simple testinga [13927101801]

Then you could do this:

```
$content = do_shortcode(get_the_content());
preg_match_all('/\[(\d{11}|\w{10})(?:\s*"([^"]+)")?\]\/', $content, $matches);

$matches = array_slice($matches, 1);
$matches = call_user_func_array( 'array_map', array_merge(array(NULL), $matches) );

var_dump($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '13927101801' (length=11) // <-- ID
      1 => string 'Caption' (length=7)      // <-- Caption content
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'mqEqHAC3rK' (length=10) // <-- ID
      1 => string 'caption' (length=7)     // <-- Caption content
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '13927101801' (length=11) // <-- ID
      1 => string '' (length=0)           // <-- No Caption content
```

And you will get the array of `id` and (Optional) `caption`